# How do you interpolate a value that wraps around?

Tags: javascript, math, lerp

I'm making a game in JavaScript in which I need to interpolate the result from the `Math.atan2` function (which wraps around at 180 degrees to -180 degrees). Currently I just a lerp function, shown below

```
function lerp(a, b, t) {
    return a + (b - a) * t
}

rotation = lerp(rotation, newRotation, 0.2)
```

The problem with this implementation is that when `newRotation` wraps around, `rotation` spins all the way around the opposite way to reach it. I attempted to solve this by checking both their signs before deciding to lerp or not

```
if (Math.sign(rotation) == Math.sign(newRotation)) {
     rotation = lerp(rotation, newRotation, 0.2)
} else {
     rotation = newRotation
}
```

And while it no longer spins all the way around, if `newRotation` is even somewhat far from `rotation`, then it akwardly jumps to `newRotation` and defeats the whole purpose of interpolation.

So my question is if there's a way to have `rotation` smoothly transition to `newRotation` through the wraparound point.

Comment: What is the lerp function? What is it based on? And are you using degeres instead of radians?

Comment: @ControlAltDel OP has their lerp function in the question

Comment: [Lerp rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970781/js-how-to-lerp-rotation-in-radians)